# FsharpCharts for silverlight / f#

Tags: silverlight, f#, charts, fsharpchart

This might be a stupid question, but there are soo many combinations of approach (wpf, silverlight, winforms, html5) with incompatibility at mscorlib level, that I got completely lost.

I would like to be able to have a few windows mainly displaying realtime *charts*.
Probably with interaction among the windows (click in one, pop and display a new windows)
If it can be viewed on the web, perfect.

But I dont want to have to deal with another layer of nasty stuff for those features (like having to setup some "WCF" on a "IIS", kill me first)

In the end I was thinking of using FSharpChart on Silverlight.
Is that possible and/ or the best option ?

Thanks for your suggestions

**update**

I see that system.drawing which fsharpchart relies on is not silverlight supported..

Comment: Take a look at @JonHarrop's tutorials here: http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/search/label/tutorial

Comment: You can always look at any Silverlight charting library (there are answers here listing these), these are useable from F# anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try Dynamic Data Display instead of FSharpChart. It runs on Silverlight: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/groups/science/tools/d3/dynamicdatadisplay.htm

It's not as F# Interactive friendly as FSharpChart, but you can easily wrap it in a handful of functions to make it more usable